# Share ado.net application database with other computers

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

I'm making an ado.net app that database must be shared with other computers in the same building

I m using SQLite

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.. Please provide the code what you tried so someone can give a solution of your problem. Thanks

Comment: I'm looking for a way to share .db file that other computers application database can load it (or refresh automaticly)

Comment: You can create a wcf service that will host the SQLite database and use whatever framework you want for your client application.

Comment: if you are in  same network then create your db in a server and all clients can access that then

Comment: Thanky you guys

Answer (score 1):

You could share your .db file on a shared folder but that is not what SQLite is for.  see [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

> **Many concurrent writers? → choose client/server**
>
> If many threads and/or processes need to write the database at the same instant (and they cannot queue up and take turns) then it is best to select a database engine that supports that capability, which always means a client/server database engine.  SQLite only supports one writer at a time per database file. But in most cases, a write transaction only takes milliseconds and so multiple writers can simply take turns.
>
> SQLite will handle more write concurrency that many people suspect. Nevertheless, client/server database systems, because they have a long-running server process at hand to coordinate access, can usually handle far more write concurrency than SQLite ever will.

Also see this answer [Is it possible to use a SQLite database in a shared folder in a PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34705715/2321864)